# How not to create presenter object in view?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvp

I'm currently trying out some MVP patterns sample and I have been told not create concrete `Presenter` objects in the `View`. Is there any way to have `Presenter` objects created dynamically ?

```
public partial class View: Window, IView
{
   private Presenter _presenter;

    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _presenter = new Presenter(this); //Asked to avoid this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking it wrong. You don't create the presenter in the view. You create it elsewhere (application startup, other presenters) and it passes itself to the view, either as a constructor parameter, or by setting a property.

Like this:

```
class FooView : IFooView
{
    private readonly IFooPresenter presenter;

    public FooView(IFooPresenter presenter)
    {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }
}

class FooPresenter1 : IFooPresenter
{
    private readonly IFooView view;

    public FooPresenter1()
    {
        view = new FooView(this);
    }
}
// or
class FooPresenter2 : IFooPresenter
{
    private readonly IFooView view;

    public FooPresenter2(IFooView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        view.Presenter = this;
    }
}
```

And by the way, you seem to be using WPF. If that's the case you may want to have a look at the [Model-View-ViewModel pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/10/11/datamodel-view-viewmodel-pattern-series.aspx) instead.

Comment: This would not work in webforms. View is the first one that handles the request so it has to create a presenter.

Comment: @epitka: I hate webforms. Still a valid point though. I just assumed he was doing some desktop stuff since his View inherits from Window.

Answer (score 2):

With *view first* creation you can use an IoC container to create your Presenter:

```
public View(IMyPresenter presenter)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _presenter = presenter;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use *model (presenter) first* where the View is passed to the Presenter in much the same way. See [Which came first, the View or the Model?](http://wildermuth.com/2009/05/22/Which_came_first_the_View_or_the_Model) for discussion on this topic.

Or you could use a third object to bind the View and Presenter together, like the [`IBinder` service](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IBinder%20and%20Convention%20over%20Configuration&referringTitle=Service%20Index) in Caliburn.